# Can we get email Id from Facebook application?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

Can an application check if anybody is logged into Facebook application in mobile ,if logged in get the user email Id from that and use it in their application?

Comment: You first need to ask for permission from user. Once user authenticates, you can get his profile information. Do mentioned the type of information you want while asking for permission.

Answer (score 0):

To get a logged in users email address, you would have to authenticate with the API and the user would have to approve you using the Oauth workflow.

You can display a customized login / connect button using the Facebook API but if I recall correctly, that is an iframe that is embedded in your page, and you never see the email from that.

tldr; No. You need to authenticate using the Oauth workflow and have the user grant you permission.

Comment: I meant FB application installed in mobile, can it provide email id of the user to  another application installed in the same mobile.

Comment: Not unless the application is authenticated and the user approves it.

If I call the facebook login method, then I need to approve the app before I get any data back about the user.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to authenticate user and then you can get logged in user profile information. For that you have to use Facebook API. Please check below link.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.2